# Duplicated domain admin user profile?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, user-profile

Our domain admin logon on PCs or Servers used to have only one profile located on

```
c:\users\administrator
```

Somehow, now we got a duplicated profile called

```
c:\users\administrator.domain
```

Does anyone know why?

Win 7 sp1

Win 2008 R2

Win 2012 R2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably nothing to worry about - this will occur when the original local profile folder doesn't unload or is otherwise corrupted.

Basically, the first profile will be

`C:\Users\username`

If there's an issue with the `username` folder, it'll append the domain name:

`C:\Users\username.domain`

If there's an issue with the `username.domain` folder, it'll then start a numerical sequence:

`C:\Users\username.domain.000`

`C:\Users\username.domain.001`

And so on.

With the "Administrator" account in particular, it could also be caused by a name clash betwen the local administrator account and the domain administrator account.

Either way, this is all just part of Windows Profile Management (Or it's lack of, I guess you could say) and unless you're having a specific issue I'd just forget about it.

Comment: I would mention the name clash first. I would say that is the most common reason for the ".domain" suffix to the profile folder. Seems to be the more logical order for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'll add to Dan's answer is if you choose to change the name of that profile folder, say back to `C:\users\username`, then you have to change the path in the registry as well, under

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<GUID>\ProfileImagePath`